# Ignore numeric values in string, Presto

Tags: presto

I have a column in a database which is all postcodes. I want to use that column to get statistical data about specific regions. To do this, I want to extract just the first non numeric characters of the postcode (B for Birmingham, BT for Belfast).

I can see solutions in other SQL formats using a CASE WHEN with ISNUMERIC but that function doesn't work in Presto. Are there any solutions to this?

As always, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to look at using regular expression functions to either extract the non-numeric characters using `regexp_extract` or replace all non-numeric characters using `regex_replace`.

See https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for your help here. Unfortunately, regexp_extract seems to fall over using it this way. It seems there is no way around this issue using this particular brand of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this using

```
select concat(substr(postcode,1,1), case when substr(postcode,2,1) in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0') then '' else substr(postcode,2,1) end)
```